# How to recover data from a damaged external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

Is it possible to recover data from a damaged external drive? My external drive was not recognized by my computers and after a computer engineer examined it, I was told the drive is damaged.

He claimed to have been able to view some of the files on the drive, but that they are damaged. How do I recover my files from this drive?

Comment: Please provide the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: What file system was on the drive? Please provide enough information so that we can answer properly.

Comment: I had good luck with `testdisk` as referenced in the duplicate candidate above.

Answer (score 0):

you need 3 things:

clonezilla http://clonezilla.org/

extundelete available n the repo

and a good drive.

use clonezilla to do a sector by sect clone of the drive. this will copy all that can be copied to the new drive.

run extundelete on the new drive.

see what data you have recovered.

Comment: OP never mentioned that the file system is ext.

Comment: @Anrea true, but clonezilla will work on any fs, and prevent further loss

Comment: I honestly don't remember perfectly, but didn't Clonezilla only copy allocated sectors and apply compression? Wouldn't maybe ddrescue be a better tool to clone it thoroughly?

Comment: it can copy disk to disk, partition to partiton, and do a raw sector by sector clone.